# Запись из переменной в базу данных и чтение из базы в переменную в Qt creator

Tags: c++, sql, qt

Необходимо при запуске программы записывать данные из базы в переменные, а при ее завершении записывать данные этих переменных в базу. Сам файл с базой я создал, но не знаю какие методы использовать чтобы записать значение одной переменной в конкретную ячейку базы и наоборот, из ячейки в переменную.

Имеются на данный момент такие штуки:

```
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("./mainDB.db");
    db.open();

    query = new QSqlQuery(db);
    query->exec("CREATE TABLE DataBase(Name TEXT, Lvl INT, Cost INT);");

    model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);
    model->setTable("DataBase");
    model->select();
    model->insertRow(model->rowCount());
```

Во всех гайдах которые я пересмотрел используют QTableView чтобы туда записывать все в ручную, но в моей программке нужно сохранять данные пользователя. Сама же база находится на устройстве пользователя, не удаленно.

Comment: изучите запросы `sql`, `SELECT` для запроса данных из базы, `INSERT` и `UPDATE` для того чтобы заносить данные в базу, не забывайте производить `COMMIT`

Comment: В [документации QSqlQuery](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquery.html#details) есть примеры записи/получения значений. Альтернативный вариант: вам не обязательно выводить `QSqlTableModel` на какой-либо itemView. Вы можете просто использовать `setData`/`data` для занесения и получения значений и `insertRecord` для вставки новых строк.

Comment: insertRecord принимает в качестве параметра объект QSqlRecord, setData - QModelIndex и QVariant. Что в этих объектах должно храниться?

Comment: @Леонид, способ с `QSqlQuery` является предпочтительным, как для понимания принципов работы с бд, так и с точки зрения гибкости. `QSqlRecord` можно получить с помощью метода `record()` и установить в нём значения через `setValue`. По `data`/`setData` лучше прочитать описание работы с моделями в [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html#model-classes) или в примерах.

Comment: Нашел документацию по sqlquery на русском и решил попробовать - https://codeshare.io/OdroXv prepare() срабатывает, at() выдает -2, а при попытке достать значение из базы выдает 0 либо "".

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример, как можно вытащить из базы данные и получить их в вашем проекте:

```
QString request = QString("SELECT * from database_name;");
QSqlQuery q(request);
while(q.next())
{
    int32_t id = q.value(0).toInt();
    QString name = q.value(1).toString();
}
```